# No mapping found for HTTP request Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, mapping

I have some problem with my project.

I can successfully go to login page but after clicking the submit button I am getting this error:

```
Lis 16, 2015 4:30:01 ODP. org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/j_spring_security_check] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
```

from this line in jsp:

```
<form name='loginForm'
    action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />" method='POST'>
```

this is my spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/adminPage**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

        <form-login
                login-page="/login"
                default-target-url="/"
                authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
                username-parameter="username"
                password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"  />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <csrf/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="kk" password="1" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

this is my web.xml

```
<web-app version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


</web-app>
```

Could somebody help me? Thank you

Comment: What happens when you change the url from /j_spring_security_check to just j_spring_security_check without a leading slash?

Comment: It doesnt work. It shows red color, I cant change it in code.

Comment: <your_application_context>/j_spring_security_check where application context would be /mvc-dispatcher/spring_security_check - you should be able to make changes to your form's action method in the login page.

Comment: with this I get: 
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/mvc-dispatcher/j_spring_security_check] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `/login` instead of `/j_spring_security_check` or configure `login-processing-url` to `/j_spring_security_check`, see [Spring Security Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-form-login-attributes):

> - **login-processing-url** Maps to the `filterProcessesUrl` property of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`. The default value is "/login".